# can someone please check the code it does not work

Tags: powershell

I would like to install the selected programs and drivers on a newly created folder on a remote computer. unfortunately it does not work properly... Does anyone know what this could be or has a tip for me I am relatively new to Powershell. Thanks for your answers

```
$handler_submitwindow2_Click= 
{
$Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Computer Name you are accessing'
New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
#----------Install Software On PC----------#
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ".\%systemroot%\Temp\FileTransfer" 
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ".\%systemroot%\Temp\DriverInstallation"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path ".\%systemroot%\Temp\SoftwareInstallation" 

    Copy-Item $openFileDialog1 ".\%systemroot%\Temp\FileTransfer" -Recurse
    Copy-Item $openFileDialog2 ".\%systemroot%\Temp\DriverTransfer" -Recurse
    Copy-Item $OpenFileDialog3 ".\%systemroot%\Temp\SoftwareInstallation" -Recurse

    Write-Host "Software and Drivers get installed on $Computer"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process  $openFileDialog2 -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait}  
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process  $OpenFileDialog3 -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait}  
}
```

Comment: Try removing the ``.\`` in front of `%systemroot%` in all the paths. The ``.\`` indicates the current directory. This doesn't make sense if you're gonna use a variable. Also see @Theo 's suggestion

Comment: You are using commandline syntax on the environment variable `%systemroot%`. In PowerShel you use these variables as `$env:SystemRoot`. Also, your question does not say what variables `$openFileDialog1` .. `$openFileDialog3` contain, probably the file paths to the original setup folders. Start-Process wants the full path and filename of the **executable** you need to run (like .exe or .msi).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I have changed the paths to `$env:SystemRoot.... ` changed. In the `openFileDialog` are the previously selected programs and drivers so in the `OpenFileDialog2 .msi` and in the `OpenFiledialog3 .exe` how can I now insert the endings in the code ? does that simply eb `Start-Process $openFileDialog.exe` or how do I have to do that ?

Comment: You don't need to insert any extensions if an executable is picked in those file dialogs.

Comment: Please edit/rollback your question to the way it was before we answered your question, or else your question will not make sense to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two mistakes here.

You are using the `.\` operator, which represents the current directory. You then attempt to use the environment variable `%systemroot%`, which would resolve to something like:

```
C:\Your\Current\Directory\C:\Windows\Temp\FileTransfer
```

Which is wrong. You should remove that operator if you're not using a relative path from your current directory.

In addition, as @Theo mentioned in the comments, `%systemroot%` does not work in PowerShell. You must instead use the syntax `$env:SystemRoot`.

Therefore, your final script would look like this:

```
$handler_submitwindow2_Click= 
{
    $Computer = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the Computer Name you are accessing'
    New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
    #----------Install Software On PC----------#
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\FileTransfer" 
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\DriverInstallation"
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\SoftwareInstallation" 

    Copy-Item $openFileDialog1 "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\FileTransfer" -Recurse
    Copy-Item $openFileDialog2 "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\DriverTransfer" -Recurse
    Copy-Item $OpenFileDialog3 "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\SoftwareInstallation" -Recurse

    Write-Host "Software and Drivers get installed on $Computer"

    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process  $openFileDialog2 -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait}  
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process  $OpenFileDialog3 -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more recommendations for your script:

1. `New-PSSession $computer` creates a connection to another computer, but doesn't cause the following commands to run over there. You would want to use something like `Invoke-Command` or `Enter-PSSession` like you do later in your script.
2. The files and folders you need can be copied remotely using the default `Admin$` share on windows, which links to the system directory:

```
# Create folders
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\$Computer\Admin$\Temp\FileTransfer" 
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\$Computer\Admin$\Temp\DriverInstallation"
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path "\\$Computer\Admin$\Temp\SoftwareInstallation" 

# Copy installation files
Copy-Item $openFileDialog1 "\\$Computer\Admin$\Temp\FileTransfer" -Recurse
Copy-Item $openFileDialog2 "\\$Computer\Admin$\Temp\DriverTransfer" -Recurse
Copy-Item $OpenFileDialog3 "\\$Computer\Admin$\Temp\SoftwareInstallation" -Recurse
```

3. If you want to use your local variables like `$openFileDialog1` When using `Invoke-Command`, you must specify the `Using:` scope to tell powershell you want the local ones and not something from the remote machine:

```
Write-Host "Installing Software and Drivers on $Computer"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process  "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\DriverTransfer\$Using:openFileDialog2" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait
  Start-Process  "$env:SystemRoot\Temp\SoftwareInstallation\$Using:OpenFileDialog3" -ArgumentList "/q" -Wait
}
```